# Postman from Chrome: how to manually login before post

Tags: google-chrome, postman

I need to use Postman to test an administative area with a PHP-based session login. How can I manually login with Postman so that the session cookie is created?

Copy and pasting the session cookie is ok too, but I cannof find where to paste it!

[This](https://www.getpostman.com/docs/postman/sending_api_requests/cookies) looks like it, but I have no `Cookies` link next to `Send` (Chrome Extension)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the Postman Chrome extension you have to use the [Postman Interceptor to manage cookies](http://blog.getpostman.com/2014/11/28/using-the-interceptor-to-read-and-write-cookies/).

If you use the [native apps](https://www.getpostman.com/apps) for your operating system, you can manage cookies [directly from the app](https://www.getpostman.com/docs/postman/sending_api_requests/cookies). Using the native app is the recommended approach.